# Question asking for specific library: borderline or close on sight?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

So, [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20495713/1079354) I'm referring to.  It's asking, quite pointedly, for API code for MtGox/PubNub in Java.

Normally I'd vote to close this as "asking for off-site resources", but there is an answer coming from one of the vendors (in this case, PubNub), in regards to the API.

My gut is still telling me that this is off-topic, since it's asking for a resource, but I do notice that there is an attempt at something to be done with it - they want to do **X** with this resource, where **X** is defined in their example source code.  My gut is telling me that's not quite enough to excuse it from being a recommendation question - and there are one or two link-only answers already on it.

Is my first gut reaction correct?  Should this question be closed?   In the future, should I react this way to these sorts of questions - in which a vendor provides a link to their third party API and resources on SO?  What does everyone think here?

I'm undecided, so instead of casting a close vote or abstaining, I came here first to ask questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question was an outright request for library suggestions, which is definitely off topic.  However, the response by [PubNub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524733/pubnub) and the answer provided is pretty good and imho of use to the community.

So, I've edited the question to remove the request for outside resources.  It only took a few seconds, and should render the question on topic.

Comment: Seems that it was closed recently - and by a diamond. I still didn't like the way it read even after it was edited, but maybe I'm picky.

Answer (score 4):

Certain questions fit into the topic area of SO, but still they are considered off-topic for more important reasons. For example questions which are known to "tend to attract opinionated answers and spam" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

According to the above quoted page, questions "asking us to recommend or find a [...] library" are of this nature. Here it is important to notice that the intention for banning these questions is to prevent undesired responses to it. I think it is safe to say that undesired responses are those which do not help the community.

Questions asking for recommendations are likely to attract spam, because often libraries are competing for market shares, even open-source libraries might compete because there can be other business models behind them besides selling licenses.

On the other hand, if a questions asks for a hard to find library, or a possibly unpublished library in a field where none exists yet, there is no competition, thus no spam will follow. The undesired responses are unlikely, thus the reason for the banning is not fulfilled and responses are likely to help the community.

However, it is hard to identify if there is competition in such an area / if a certain question is likely to draw undesired responses, and this can even change over time. Thus such a meta-decision is clearly open for speculation. Therefor, I think it is best to close these questions or ask the OP to rephrase them. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic tells how such a question can be rephrased:

> Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

This way of rephrasing a library question is always possible. So the OP is not left alone, provided that the people voting to close a question leave comments on why/how to improve the question.

The answers of course can still recommend a library, but the questions do not anymore draw such responses unless the recommendation of a library is a good and helpful answer.

Comment: Btw, I really do feel honored to be referenced in a meta-question. Because my SO question is referenced in this meta-question, I will not rephrase the SO question, although by now I would know how to make it better. I already got the answer I needed and if it gets closed, then it deserved it.